# Optimize Postgres Query from SELECT to JOIN (?)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently have a psql query that looks like the one below. It takes forever to execute, about 1:30. I would like to optimize this query possibly but not having to do several SELECT statements on the same query.

```
SELECT 

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM message WHERE message.created_by_client_id = v_client.id) AS "inboundMessages",

(SELECT v_form."isReceived" FROM v_form 
WHERE (v_form."client" ->> 'id')::integer = v_client."id" 
AND v_form."formTypeId" = 1
LIMIT 1 ) AS "isIntakeReceived",

(SELECT v_form."isReceived" FROM v_form 
WHERE (v_form."client" ->> 'id')::integer = v_client."id" 
AND v_form."formTypeId" = 2
LIMIT 1 ) AS "isFollowUpReceived",
* 
FROM v_client
```

I've tried re-writing the SELECTS as joints however they return multiple rows. I only need the latest form and the count of all the messages that were created by a client.

Comment: You (or someone else) decided to store the client data in JSON. This is a valid approach. It is decision to store the data as a whole and not be too interested in its separate contents. It is easy and quick to store the content, but access to its members is slow (e.g. looking for rows that match a certain client ID). But this is exactly what your query does. Even twice. So, this query should be an exception and you should live with its poor performance, because this is a design decision. If there are more such queries and performance is an issue, consider changing the database design.

Comment: The `LIMIT 1` without `ORDER BY` look like defense against undesired data, by the way. Why can there be multiple matches you must fend off by picking a row arbitrarily?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, perhaps it helps:

```
SELECT q.*,
       count(*) AS "inboundMessages"
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (v_client.id)
             v_client.*,
             f1."isReceived" AS "isIntakeReceived",
             f2."isReceived" AS "isFollowUpReceived"
      FROM v_client
         JOIN v_form AS f1
            ON (f1."client" ->> 'id')::integer = v_client."id" 
               AND f1."formTypeId" = 1
         JOIN v_form AS f2
            ON (f2."client" ->> 'id')::integer = v_client."id" 
               AND f2."formTypeId" = 2) AS q
   JOIN message
      ON message.created_by_client_id = q.id
GROUP BY /* all columns from "q" */;
```

Indexes that can help with your original query:

- on `v_form (((client ->> 'id')::integer), "formTypeId")`
- on `message (created_by_client_id)`